# SetWidht Half of match_parent

Tags: android, width, android-relativelayout

I need that my Relative Layout always have the half of the match_parent Width, How can I do that?

`<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/new_post_nsfw_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/new_post_image"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/new_post_image"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp">
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: You can't.  What I've done in the past is create a dummy View and set it to centerInParent.  Then specify to leftOf for one component and toRightOf for the other.

Comment: Better use LinearLayout with weight